# <AWS CodePipeline> Can I have 2 source stages, one after another, in CodePipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

I would like to implement a CI/CD flow for ECS blue/green deployment. The flow I have in mind is that, after code is checked in to GitHub, it will trigger CodeBuild to build the docker image and upload to ECR. It would then trigger a source stage to fetch the docker image from ECR, and then proceed towards a deploy stage where CodeDeploy will perform the task definition update based on the fetched docker image, in turn updates the appspec.yaml and then update the ECS service in blue/green manner.

The thing I am not certain is whether it is possible to have a second source stage to fetch the docker image? Will it trigger all source stages at once and result in kind of dead loop?

Another thought is that if I instead put it as a parallel action at the same source stage at the beginning, can I set the ECR pull action to wait after the docker image is built first?

## Pipeline flow:

First source stage:
Get source from GitHub

Build Stage:
Build docker image and upload to ECR

Second source stage:
Get docker image from ECR

Deploy stage:
Get tag from the docker image, update taskdef.json with the image tag, then update appspec.yaml with the updated task definition, then deploy to ECS

Comment: Why do you need to pull the docker image you just built? 
You could either pass the built image tag by artifact (e.g. JSON file) or by convention (e.g. commit ID of the first source stage)

Comment: @Pistazie yes you are right. I found out from documentation that we can have an "imageDetail.json" to be generated in the build phase. In the CodePipeline build phase, it can optionally update the docker image tag and create an "imageDetail.json" which specifies the image URI. In the deploy phase, CodeDeploy will update the taskdef.json with the image URI, thus creating a new task definition. This will in turn update the appspec.yaml with the updated task definition. This will then trigger the ECS blue/green deployment using the updated task definition and docker image.